# Adding MySQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been instructed to update the following tables in OSTICKET MYSQL as follows:

update the database [please edit this to fit your installation] with the following MySQL Queries:

```
ALTER TABLE ost_ticket CHANGE status status ENUM('open','closed','pending') DEFAULT    'open';

ALTER TABLE ost_ticket_event CHANGE state state ENUM('created','closed','reopened','assigned','transferred','o
```

How would I do that using phpmyadmin ?

Comment: A side note: the second query is incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on the SQL tab, paste it, and submit it
Also your last SQL command is cut off atleast I hope it was

Answer (score 1):

Click on the SQL tab.
Type in your SQL query.
Click on Go to execute the query.

you are missing end bracket in 2nd query

```
ALTER TABLE ost_ticket_event CHANGE state state ENUM('created','closed','reopened','assigned','transferred','o');
```

[Running SQL Query on databases with phpMyAdmin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sZOwKfOJ1U)

Comment: Yes I had to look into the actual html of the page with the instructions to find the correct completed code. For some reason it didn’t display correctly and did not copy correctly. Should be like this :

    `ALTER TABLE ost_ticket_event CHANGE state state ENUM('created','closed','reopened','assigned','transferred','overdue','pending')`

Comment: @DanielBaker ok ok.If my answer is useful make upvote/mark as useful

Answer (score 0):

Write Your query as:

```
ALTER TABLE  `tablename` CHANGE  `columnname`  `columnname` datatype( size/values ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '2'

ex:-
ALTER TABLE  `ost_ticket_event` CHANGE  `status`  `status` ENUM( 'open','close','pending' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'pending'
```